# Isn't it wrong to use the word "homage" as a countable noun in this book?

Tags: indefinite-article, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I came across this line in the book *Ship of Theseus*(p.14):

> It's just an homage to his writing.

[image]

（the hand-written notes filling the book's margins are printed and an inseparable part of the book.）

I've never seen the word "homage" being used as a countable noun before, and having got an "an" before it?

Isn't it wrong to use the word "homage" as a countable noun?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Homage" is a countable noun, in the sense of "an act done in tribute of or respect for something". (in fact it's the usual meaning of the word nowadays)

[An entry, showcasing meanings and different pronunciations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homage)

Also, the reason why the writer put *an* before "homage" is because the pronunciation of *homage* is kind of all over the place, with some pronunciations having the H silent.

Comment: In my experience (native speaker of British English, somewhat backed up by your link), it's usually pronounced as a French word (omm-ahj) when it's used literally or figuratively in the sense of "an artistic tribute" and as a naturalized English word (homm-ij) elsewhere, e.g., in the phrase "pay homage to".

Answer (score 5):

Homage is definitely countable, although it is rarely used in the plural.

The typical modern meaning of [homage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homage) (definition 2 at the link) is a special and notable honor paid to someone, so it is unusual that more than one such honor would be paid at a time.  That said, it is entirely possible for such a thing to occur, and *homages* is definitely a word that is used in English, and the MW link I provided includes an example of how it might be used.

> his long life filled with international homages to his unique musical talent

Saying that a work of art (literary, musical, visual, etc) is *an homage* to another artist is a common expression.

Comment: I hate the modern meaning, and the reversion to French pronunciation, but there's no denying it exists.

Comment: I'm fine with the modern meaning, but the French-style pronunciation feels kind of pretentious.